Escape forward in curl command in URL
I have an API route like this: /api/query/{ip} which for ip users could pass an IP address or network.
How can I escape / in 1.1.1.0/24 network with curl command so my backend route can reach and assign ip = "1.1.1.0/24"
I have tried this but it's not working.
curl "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/query/ip/1.1.1.0\\/24"


Solved, this worked: curl "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/query/ip/1.1.1.0%2F24"

You can (and you are encouraged to) answer your own question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
slash's (/) ASCII Code is 47 or 2F in hexa.
Thus, / in URL that does not want to be treated as normal / should be replaced with: %2F
